# Disable the internet without touching the hardware

Tags: registry, controls, tweak

How would I go about disabling the internet on my computer without touching the hardware (modem, router, etc) and without disabling it from the Network Connections of the Control Panel. Is there a way to tweak it on the **registry** instead?

I'm wanting to achieve this to control my younger sister's usage of our computer at home. She's kinda getting addicted so my mom suggested that I make an application that can do such thing when a certain time is hit. *E.g.* when the time is 10pm the internet gets disabled automatically so she won't have anything to do and shut down the comp instead.

I already know how to deal with checking the time and such but the only thing I'm missing is the registry tweak required for it.

Thank you for those who'd answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the command line commands described here:http://www.asp101.com/articles/stanley/nicsettings/default.asp to change the ip address to something that won't work or a bogus dns server?  You could have your time-checking application call the batch file or simply execute the command.

Comment: Hmm I would want to keep it in the registry though.. Without needing help from Windows' command lines...

Comment: Most registry modifications needs windows restart so it is not such a good idea. You should use a command line command, but not directly: if you have any windows programming experience the write a small application that will run the command at the specific time. Or you can use save the script as a .bat file and using windows task scheduler run it at 10PM

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking the registry is pretty much a **bad idea**, leading to the need to reinstall Windows. You should look at the parental controls to set access time restrictions. Ideally your sister will have her own account on the computer, allowing you to set restrictions.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the case because when the computer was originally set up it was only for one person... Creating a new user would bog down the already slow computer...